# Easy and reasonable secure way to identify a specific network

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, authorization

We like to enable some hidden features of our software only if it is run inside of the company network. The key requirements are:

- no need for a third party library outside of DotNet 4.5.1
- easy to implement (should not be more than some dozens of lines .. I don't want to reimplement a crypto library)
- It should be reasonable safe:

  - at least: hard to reverse engineer
  - at best: "impossible" to break even with read-access to the source code
- low maintenance overhead
- Win2012-Server is available for installation of additional software (open source or own implementation prefered - server can be assumed to be safe)

What I have thought about:

1. Check if a specific PC is available with a known MAC or IP (current implementation, not really secure and some other flaws)
2. Test, if a service is available on a specific response (i.e. I send 'Hello' to MyServer:12345 - server responses with 'World')
3. Similar to 2nd but a more complex challenge (i.e. send a seed for a RNG to the server, verify the response)
4. Set up an apache with HTTPS and verify the certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've choosen the last option: Set up a webserver in the intranet and verify the certificate.

It was easier than expected. There are enough tutorials for setting up an apache with https for every supported OS. The self-signed certificate have a lifetime of 9999 days - should be okay until 2042. The C#-part is also reasonable small:

```
  private static bool m_isHomeLocation = false;
  public static bool IsHomeLocation
  {
      get
      {
          if (m_isHomeLocation)
              return true;
          try
          {
              HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://yourLicenseServer:yourConfiguredPort");
              request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ((s, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
              HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
              response.Close();
              var thumbprint = new X509Certificate2(request.ServicePoint.Certificate).Thumbprint;
              m_isHomeLocation = (thumbprint == "WhateverThumbprintYourCertificateHave");                    
          }
          catch
          {
              // pass - maybe next time
          }
          return m_isHomeLocation;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ActiveDirectory, you could add a reference to the System.DirectoryServices namespace and check

```
ActiveDirectorySite currentSite = ActiveDirectorySite.GetComputerSite();
```

then you can get a bit of information from the currentSite object and check against that. That's how I enable/disable features of an application I'm developing currently.

I also grab:

```
var client = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (var ip in client.AddressList)
{
    if(ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        ipAddress = ip;
    }
}
```

Which you can check to make sure the client is connected with the proper protocol.